# How to add function pointer in a tailq in C

Tags: c, function-pointers, memcpy

I need to hold **char *title** and **int (*callback)(void *, unsigned int)** variables pair in a tailq. Because there is another thread mechanism in my full code and it checks this global 'identifier' variable when triggered. I used memcpy but it did not work.

How can I do that?

The code snip is below.

```
struct callback_list_entry {
    int (*callback)(void *, unsigned int);
    char *title;
    TAILQ_ENTRY(callback_list_entry) entries;
};
TAILQ_HEAD(callback_list, callback_list_entry);
struct sipc_identifier
{
    unsigned int port;
    int (*broadcast_callback)(void *, unsigned int);
    struct callback_list callback_list;
};

typedef struct sipc_identifier _sipc_identifier;

static _sipc_identifier identifier;

int my_callback(void *prm, unsigned int len)
{
    printf("here is %s: %s len: %d\n", __func__, (char *)prm, len);

    return OK;
}
static int add_callback_to_callback_list(int (*callback)(void *, unsigned int), char *title, _sipc_identifier *identifier)
{
    struct callback_list_entry *entry = NULL;

    if (!callback || !identifier) {
        errorf("args cannot be NULL\n");
        return NOK;
    }

    entry = (struct callback_list_entry *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct callback_list_entry));
    if (!entry) {
        errorf("calloc failed\n");
        return NOK;
    }

debugf("%p and size %d  title: %s  %p\n", callback, (int)sizeof(callback), title, &callback);

    entry->callback = (void *)calloc(1, sizeof(callback));
    if (!entry->callback) {
        errorf("calloc failed\n");
        FREE(entry);
        return NOK;
    }
    memcpy(entry->callback, callback, sizeof(callback));

debugf("entry->callback %p  %p\n", entry->callback, *(entry->callback));

    entry->title = (char *)calloc(1, strlen(title) + 1);
    if (!entry->title) {
        errorf("calloc failed\n");
        FREE(entry->callback);
        FREE(entry);
        return NOK;
    }
    strcpy(entry->title, title);

    TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(&identifier->callback_list, entry, entries);

    return OK;
}


static int register(char *title, int (*callback)(void *, unsigned int))
{
    if (!title || !callback) {
        errorf("args cannot be NULL\n");
        return NOK;
    }

    return add_callback_to_callback_list(callback, title, &identifier);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    TAILQ_INIT(&identifier->callback_list);

    register("App_A_Registered_title", &my_callback);

    return OK;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your callback is just a pointer, don't need to calloc, etc, jsut assign it with the value. But you (may) need it for the string.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Thanks for the help.